# MSACCESS. Forms- Dropdown to update foreign key

Tags: ms-access

```
 Tables
 Company- CompanyID, CountryID , Company Name, 
 Country-CountryID, Country Name
```

I am creating a form to edit the company information. I am having problems updating Company's CountryID. I want a dropdown to displays every country which will modify the company's foreign key.

I followed the tutorial here. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/comboboxes/bind_index.php. It works with inner but it doesn't display all the countries. But when I switched SQL inner to left join, the form fails.

My sql-

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT table_country.Country, table_company.Country_id
FROM table_country LEFT JOIN table_company ON table_country.Country_id = table_company.Country_id
ORDER BY table_country.Country;
```

[image]

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: What does yur complete query look like?

Comment: Its above the pic. I added my form interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the `RowSource` property of the `combobox` should only contain a lookup list. It should not be retrieving records from the company table.

The `RowSource` property should be:

```
SELECT Country_ID, Country FROM table_country ORDER BY Country
```

Set `Column Count` to `2`

Set `Bound Column` to `1`

Set `Column Width` to `0` as you don't want to display the `country_id` only `country`.